# creating independent controllers in angular with ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to angular and trying to create new login app, i want to  maintain separate controller but when separate the controllers from controllers.js I am getting function got undefined error.

here is My code:

app.js

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
 // MainCtrl.js

  angular.module('myapp.controllers', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', 
    function($scope, $state) {
        console.info("inside main ctrl");
});


 //
```

```html
//index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/LoginCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/MainCtrl.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/controllers.js"></script> -->


  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller = "MainCtrl">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>


login.html
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="login-view">
  <ion-content class="padding">
      <div class="list list-inset">
          <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.username">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
          </label>
      </div>
      <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

got this error:

ionic.bundle.js:26771 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'LoginCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ng/areq?p0=LoginCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at ionic.bundle.js:13415
    at assertArg (ionic.bundle.js:15191)
    at assertArgFn (ionic.bundle.js:15201)
    at $controller (ionic.bundle.js:23350)
    at self.appendViewElement (ionic.bundle.js:59763)
    at Object.switcher.render (ionic.bundle.js:57874)
    at Object.switcher.init (ionic.bundle.js:57794)
    at self.render (ionic.bundle.js:59623)
    at self.register (ionic.bundle.js:59581)
    at updateView (ionic.bundle.js:65261)

The code works as expected if I replace the **myapp.controller** with **starter.controller** in LoginCtrl.js and adding **starter.controller** along with **myapp.controller** in app.js.

angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'myapp.controllers', 'starter.controllers'])

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

.state('login', {
    cache:false,
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  });

   // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');


 // LoginCtrl.js

  angular.module('starter.controllers',[])
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state){
    $scope.login = function() {
        console.log("LOGIN user");
        // $state.go('app.home')
      }
});
```

Comment: It's unclear which part of this code is the working code and which is the broken code, since you mention that it works as expected with certain changes.  However, it *appears* that you are **creating** the `.controllers` module twice;  my guess is that you have `angular.module('myapp.controllers',[])` present in both js files;  The second creation essentially overwrites the first.  you should only create the module once, use the getter syntax everywhere else (`angular.module('myapp.controllers')`)

Comment: see https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y023